# What should my admin/posts edit url look like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My routes has:

```
namespace :admin do
     resource :posts

  end
```

I tried this link:

```
<a href="<%= edit_admin_posts_path @post %>">edit</a>
```

it generates:

```
/admin/posts/edit.my-post-title
```

What should the edit page look like, rake routes shows this:

```
/admin/posts/edit(.:format)
```

not sure what that format means?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use `resources`, not `resource`. Using the singular form is not appropriate when you try to create a path by supplying a resource id.

With `resources` the path helper is:

```
edit_admin_post => GET /admin/posts/:id/edit(.:format)
  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
```

and `edit_admin_post_path(@post)` should work.

`:format` refers to the various formats that the controller might respond with, i.e .html, .xml, etc